# Getting syntax error on Filtered index creation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to add this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [HE_MissingIndex] 
ON [dbo].[HardwareEvents] ([PlaceId] ASC, [EventId] ASC, [UserTokenType])
INCLUDE ([Id], [EventTime], [UserToken], [Username], [UserId],
         [VisitorId], [UserLastname]) 
WHERE (EventId = 16 AND UserTokenType = 5) OR EventId = 58
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, 
                ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'or'.

Which is kinda weird for me. I have consulted related MSDN page, an I don't see any constraint that fits here. Both columns in the filter are present in the index. The index is created without an OR in the expression. What am I missing here?

Comment: @marc_s Really? I don't think your edit made it clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtered Indexes only allow `AND` and `IN` predicates, so your issue is in your `WHERE` clause -- you cannot use `OR`. You could get around this by creating two indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [HE_MissingIndex] ON [dbo].[HardwareEvents]
(
    [PlaceId] ASC,
    [EventId] ASC,
    [UserTokenType] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id],
    [EventTime],
    [UserToken],
    [Username],
    [UserId],
    [VisitorId],
    [UserLastname]) 
    WHERE [EventId] = 16 and [UserTokenType] = 5
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [HE_MissingIndex_2] ON [dbo].[HardwareEvents]
(
    [PlaceId] ASC,
    [EventId] ASC,
    [UserTokenType] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id],
    [EventTime],
    [UserToken],
    [Username],
    [UserId],
    [VisitorId],
    [UserLastname]) 
    WHERE [EventId] = 58
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but I haven't found any documented constraint that I can't use OR. But I see now in the syntax, that only conjuction can be used. Will the engine use both indexes in the same query? I am not sure...

Comment: @ZorgoZ I did not find any official documentation either, only several comments on SO posts and other places.